# Error on delimited

Tags: c#

have problem with delimited on one PC but on mine is everything good.
I have WinXP but my friend Vista.

Here is the code:

```
string AccessKonekcija2 = null;
AccessKonekcija2 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\exports_blaise2\\" + textBox22.Text + ".mdb";
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection AccessExcelKonekcija = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(AccessKonekcija2); 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand AccessExcelKomanda = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(); 
AccessExcelKomanda.Connection = AccessExcelKonekcija;
 AccessExcelKomanda.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO[Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;DATABASE=C:\\exports_blaise2\\zips\\manipulai\\" + value3 + "\\" + textBox22.Text + "\\OUT].[" + value3 + "man.txt] FROM " + value3 + "man";    
AccessExcelKonekcija.Open(); AccessExcelKomanda.ExecuteNonQuery();     
AccessExcelKonekcija.Close();
```

And the error is:
[image]

Can someone tell me whats wrong ?
And how come that I can do that w/o an error.
But my friend not.

I already checked regional setting they are both equal.

Comment: check this link: [Text file specification field separator matches decimal separator or text delimiter](http://blog.van-eerde.net/post/2011/05/17/Text-file-specification-field-separator-matches-decimal-separator-or-text-delimiter.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Check the Regional Settings in Control Panel: One of the things you can set is the list separation character. The error message sounds like this could be the case. Since Excel respects this setting for `CSV` files and your code mentions Excel somewhat... give it a try?

Make sure they match. Standard (US) is `,`. Here in Switzerland, though, it is normally `;` and this can lead to subtle errors like the one you're having...